# Given a homotopy $H(s,t)$ between two closed curves, must $\varphi_s(t) = H(s,t)$ be a closed curve?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $U$ be an open set in some topology $\tau$. Let $\gamma_0$ be a closed curve parametrized by $\varphi_0(t): [0,1] \rightarrow U$ and $\gamma_1$ be a closed curve parametrized by $\varphi_1(t): [0,1] \rightarrow U$. Suppose $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ are homotopic to each other under $H: [0,1]\times [0,1] \rightarrow U$.

Given $\varphi_s(t) = H(s,t)$, must $\varphi_s(t)$ be closed? My intuition is saying yes and I just want to get checked if my idea is correct.

1. By continuity of $H(s,t)$, $\varphi_s(t)$ is a continuous function. Hence, $\varphi_s(t)$ it is a curve in $U$ with parameter $t$. Therefore, $\varphi_s((0,1))$ is connected. Since $\varphi_s([0,1])$ is not a closed curve, I am forced with a conclusion that $\varphi_s(0) \neq \varphi_s(1)$.
2. This breaks continuity assumption given that $\tau$ is Hausdorff.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, beccause $H$ is continuous. Note that $\varphi_s$ is the composition of the continuous maps $H\circ i_s$ where $i_s: [0,1]\to [0,1]^2$, $t\mapsto (s,t)$.

Comment: @s.harp sorry, I edited the question. I wanted to check if $\varphi_s(t)$ is a parametrization of some closed curve, not that it is continuous.

Comment: No, look at for example $H(s,t) = t\,\sin(\pi s)$ as a homotopy of the constant loop in $\Bbb R$. However usually for homotopies of loops you ask that $H(s,0)$ and $H(s,1)$ are _constant_ (hence you do get closed curves). The alternative, where the homotopies can be by not-closed loops, is called a free homotopy.

Comment: @s.harp Your comment should be an official answer.